# Convert my file from .CSV to .XLSX first then save it

Tags: excel, vba, csv

How to save a CSV file to XLSX

below is my code

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\1.Martin\1.Work\19.DataShi\Recon\2022\October\Data Extract" & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY")) & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: [`SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) has a *FileFormat* parameter. Also your parentheses are off, there should be no parenthesis before `C:\1.Martin...`, and only one parenthesis to close `Format`.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\1.Martin\1.Work\19.DataShi\Recon\2022\October\Data Extract" & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsx"`. Don't use parentheses with `SaveAs`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! corrected it but it just changes the extension to XLSX and it messes up my file. as it didn't convert it from CSV to XLSX

Comment: Then specify the `FileFormat` parameter.